# JAVA jdbc добавление только отсутствующей информации

Tags: java

Есть программа, которая раз в минуту записывает список процессов и отправляет их в базу данных. есть ли возможность добавлять в базу данных только процессы, которые небыли добавлены ранее? причем весь список находится в одной ячейке в БД. Если да, то как? 
код добавления записи

```
String sql =  "INSERT INTO users(proclist, ip) VALUES ( ?, ? )  on duplicate key update proclist = ?;";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, lp.toString());
preparedStatement.setString(2, ownip);
preparedStatement.setString(3, lp.toString());
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: вы бы структуру таблицы показали и пример записи в ней

Comment: вам надо просто сравнить, то что было с тем, что получено в текущий момент и потом уже обновлять. и добавьте код в вопрос.

Comment: в таблице несколько столбцов, в один из них записывается список процессов, пример данных которые туда записываются:
csrss.exe
services.exe
lsass.exe
lsm.exe
winlogon.exe
svchost.exe
svchost.exe
atiesrxx.exe

Comment: Тут два варианта: 1) как-то это дело парсить в коде и сразу писать корректный список 2) пересмотреть архитектуру БД и хранить каждый процесс в отдельной строке

Comment: если использовать отдельные строки как-то многовато их будет

Comment: и что вас смущает в количестве строк?

Comment: чтобы выделить отдельную ячейку для каждого процесса, нужно более 90 столбцов. я не уверен как это отобразится на быстродействии БД, если клиентов будет около 100 одновременно а изменения будут проходить каждые 2 минуты, а обращение к этой БД сторонним ПО каждую минуту

Comment: просто пересмотрите дизайн вашей БД. пусть процессы хранятся в отдельной таблице. а в другой таблице будут лишь внешние ключи для процессов и пользователей. это будет связь многие-ко-многим.